# How to create an admin role using explorer in Loopback 3.x?

Tags: acl, loopbackjs

I can create normal users but I've no idea how to create Admin users using the explorer. Suggest a solution please.

Comment: My suggestion: read up on [ask] on Stack Overflow. Especially list what you have already tried, because I have no idea what you want or whether you already tried anything on which we can build.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague. To be honest, your best bet is probably to work though [loopback-example-access-control](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control) and make sure you really understand the concepts behind the steps that the tutorial walks you through.

If you are asking about creating administrator users in general, then the answer is to (1) [create an "admin" Role](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#static-roles), (2) assign it to an existing User instance/record, and then (3) [edit the ACLs](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html#using-the-acl-generator-to-define-access-control) of your Models to specify what an "admin" can do (and what others shouldn't be able to do).

You can't create an "admin" user using the API Explorer "out of the box". To be able to create Admin users using the API Explorer you would need to do something along the lines of:

1. Create your own user model (e.g. AppUser) by [extending the build-in User model](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Extending-built-in-models.html).
2. [Create an "admin" Role for AppUser](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#static-roles)
3. [Specify ACLs for the 'admin' role](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html#using-the-acl-generator-to-define-access-control)
4. Add a [remote method](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html) to the the AppUser model, that applies the 'admin' Role to an AppUser instance as required.

Comment: I know that there is always a way to do it through a script, but is there any alternative to do so!? because it would be easy that way and well we can do it through the explorer defining relations between user and roles and exposing the roles and rolemapping model through the API so that we can add roles and map them with the user specified but to be honest the script way is way better.